# Does grpc-web TLS requries any config on the client side?

Tags: grpc, grpc-web

I have been looking for this for a while now. Still not sure if Envoy and Nginx does all the TLS stuff for a web-gRPC client.

In my case, my Nginx config works well with gRPC client and server. However, it is not working for web-gRPC client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx is no longer being actively supported for grpc-web. The default proxy for grpc-web is Envoy. You should be able to set up TLS by setting some config with the envoy.yaml file. In particularly, look under the 'tls_context' section.